# Is this a mistake in my exercise? A density for a transformed variable

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, measure-theory

Let $(X,Y)$ be invariant under transformations by orthogonal matrices, and let their joint density be $g(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$, where $f$ are the marginal densities. Show that $$g(x,y) = f(x)f(y) = f(0)f\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \right).$$

However, I can only show that this holds almost everywhere, by, for every $(x,y)$, determining an orthogonally transformed random variable $(X',Y')$ with density $g'(x,y) = f(0)f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$... but of course this only implies that $g'  = g$ almost everywhere.

Is this a mistake in the exercise? Or does this actually hold for all $(x,y)$?

Comment: Density functions that equal one another almost everywhere are generally regarded as belonging to the same equivalence class, and so if you have a $g^\prime$ that equals $g$ almost everywhere, you are done with the proof.

Comment: Hello Dilip. Could you expand on what you mean b "equivalence class"?

Comment: If two density functions equal one another almost everywhere (that is, the set of points where they differ is a set of probability $0$), then any probability calculation done using one density function will give the same answer as the same calculation done using the other density function. For example, $\phi(x)$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases}\phi(x), &x \neq 0,\\0, & x=0,\end{cases}$ (where $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal density) are in the same equivalence class because the set where they differ $\{0\}$ has probability measure $0$. If you found $g$ but were asked to prove $\phi$, you are OK.

Comment: @Dilip I believe the invariance under rotations can be exploited here to prove a stronger result: namely, one should be able to find a version of $f$ for which the conclusion holds exactly, not just a.e.

Comment: @whuber As you well know, an even stronger result is that if the density of $(X,Y)$ has circular symmetry (invariant under rotations) and $X$ and $Y$ are independent (as evidenced by the assumption $g(x,y) = f(x)f(Y)$), then $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables. I was just sticking to what the OP was saying.

Comment: Hello whuber. I am interested in your comment. How would we exploit the invariance under rotations to show that it holds exactly?

Comment: Exploit the smoothness of integrals. Start with any version of $f$ for the marginal density. Averaging $g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ over all rotations produces an equivalent version of the joint distribution $g$, say $\tilde g$. I believe you can show it is continuous (express it in polar coordinates), except possibly at the origin. Because the original variables are still independent, $\tilde g$ must factor as $\tilde{g}(x,y)=\tilde{f}_X(x)\tilde{f}_Y(y)$. But then $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are equivalent versions of $f$, whence $\tilde{g}$ is a version of $\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y)$ for a *continuous* $\tilde f$.

Answer (score 3):

**It's a mistake in the exercise: you made all the progress one can.**

After all, suppose there exists a continuous version of the marginal density $\tilde f$ with $\tilde{f}(0)\ne 0$ and $g(x,y)=\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y)$.  (The standard bivariate Normal distribution has this property.)

Modify $\tilde f$ to a new density $f$ by setting $\tilde{f}(0)=0$.  Because this changes $\tilde f$ only on a set $\{0\}$ of measure zero, $f$ also is a marginal density for either $X$ or $Y$.   Moreover, $f(x)f(y)$ differs from $\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y)$ at most on the set $\left(\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}\right) \cup \left(\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}\right)$, which has measure zero.  If the conclusion of the exercise were correct, it would imply

$$g(x,y)=\tilde{f}(x)\tilde{f}(y) = f(0)f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) [\text{a.e.}] = 0\times f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) = 0.$$

However, that's not a density because it integrates to zero.